# Display attribute image in category product

Tags: image, list, magento, categories

I have this files for this attribute “brand” to show up in product page:

`brands.phtml` ---- http://pastebin.com/kfiuGTdh
`adminhtml.xml` ---- http://pastebin.com/rFj4KMR4
`config.xml` ---- http://pastebin.com/ac76KLcT
`system.xml` ---- http://pastebin.com/iGdF14sc
`data.php` ---- http://pastebin.com/Zdg3VZbU
`v1_brands.xml` ---- http://pastebin.com/6mm3iBdk

and this code is for show the brand in product page, is locate in view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_attributes_placeholder'); ?>
```

I want to modify this to show the brand image in category/homepage on the each product like this:

http://postimage.org/image/op26uwz6b/

I try more options but nothing work, I don't now what to do. I hope you understand what I want.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have enabled "show attribute in product listing" in the attributes options in the magento admin?

this will make sure the attribute is loaded into the collection which is used on the listing pages / collections, otherwise you won't have it available :)